# What is the need for Name interface in Java?

Tags: java, string, interface, charsequence

In Java, when is the interface [Name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Name.html) (which extends [CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html)) useful? Why not just use `final String` instead? I do not see any classes that implement `Name`.

Alternatively, what I am interested is the use cases of [Name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/Name.html), [CharSequence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html), and the [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class.

Comment: This is part of the [package `java.lang.model.element`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/lang/model/element/package-summary.html) which is _"Interfaces used to model elements of the Java programming language."_. In other words, it is not general purpose.

Comment: And there are implementations, but just not in a public API as these interfaces are the API (e.g. in Temurin 11, there are `com.sun.tools.javac.util.Name`, `com.sun.tools.javac.util.SharedNameTable.NameImpl` and `com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable.NameImpl`).

Comment: There are other classes than just `String` that represent "text", `StringBuilder` for example. Sometimes you dont actually need to demand a `String` but can also just accept `CharSequence` and then users could also give you a `StringBuilder` and not just `String`. `Name` generally follows the same idea, it is `CharSequence` + 3 more methods. Tldr, learn what interfaces are and why they are useful.

Comment: Thank you @MarkRotteveel. Interesting. Just a follow-up question, how do we model elements of the language with the same language?

Comment: It is mostly for the meta-aspects that Java provides, in particular the reflection API that allow you to inspect the code and retrieve meta information about it, or to dynamically trigger stuff. For example call a method by its name, given by user input.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If you provide your answer, not in the comment form I will accept it and close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is more than just a String.

In the description of the `equals` method it says:

> Note that the identity of a Name is a function both of its content in
> terms of a sequence of characters as well as the implementation which
> created it.

So this implies that there is more to an object that implements `Name` than just its character representation. It also has to know about the implementation which created it.

If you want to just compare the content you have to use `contentEquals`.

But you are probably not going to be creating classes using this interface yourself. It is part of the Java language model.

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the answer based on the comments: By @Mark Rotteveel

> This is part of the package java.lang.model.element which is "Interfaces used to model elements of the Java programming language.". In other words, it is not general purpose. And there are implementations, but just not in a public API as these interfaces are the API (e.g. in Temurin 11, there are 
> com.sun.tools.javac.util.Name, 
> com.sun.tools.javac.util.SharedNameTable.NameImpl and 
> com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable.NameImpl).

And it is more than just a string based on @rghome answer.

Moreover, the reason the modeling is also provided in the same language is: By @Zabuzard

> It is mostly for the meta-aspects that Java provides, in particular the reflection API that allows you to inspect the code and retrieve meta-information about it, or to dynamically trigger stuff. For example call a method by its name, given by user input.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`CharSequence` is a very general *interface*, more so than `String`, and contrary to the obiquitous usage of `String` one could have used `CharSequence` instead, so one could pass a StringBuilder too.

However *pro* `String` (a *class*) counts its evident immutability and extra methods. Though the interface `CharSequence` itself does not have mutable functions too. As only `StringBuilder` and `String` are the most useful implementation, one may normally forget about using `CharSequence`.

`Name` is a dedicated *interface* for language modeling itself. It is a form of wrapping a value type (`String` here) in its own type for specific usage. Like wrapping a time String in a `Time`. Note that for a case-insensitive language the `Name#equals` could ignore the case (as in `PascalName implements Name`). The class/interface should not be used outside language modeling. In the model a Name may contain its declaration.